# How to pass Azure AD authentication tokens so AngularJS can use them to call webapi

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

After successful AD authentication from my MVC web app, I set the token in the header so that client side scripts can make use of it to access the web api.

OnAuthorizationCodeReceived() after a successful login

```
    private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification context)
    {
        var code = context.Code;

        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
        string userObjectID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectID));

        Uri uri = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path));

        AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, uri, credential, graphResourceId);

        HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + result.AccessToken);
    }
```

In the last line I set the "Authorization" header. However I can't seem to make use of that from my AngularJS end to make api calls! What am I missing here? Requirement is that I don't have to use ADAL to authenticate from the AngularJS since web app already authenticates the user and have passed me the valid tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to save the access token in cookie :

```
HttpCookie tokenCookies = new HttpCookie("token");
tokenCookies.Value = result.AccessToken;
tokenCookies.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);                            
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(tokenCookies);
```

Then making ajax call with access token from cookie on client side .

Comment: Calling the webapi from angular passing just the token in header doesn't work. I think there should be a way to pass the received token from client by the API back to Azure and get it authenticated and receive an Identity? [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/resources/samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi/) works well since it's using ADAL to authenticate independently from the website. In my case authentication happens from the MVC Web app and angular should only use the token to call api. Any insight is much appreciated!

Comment: I think I may be on the right track. Since I can get the token to the server side from AngularJS; I think I should validate the token manually. This [link](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-manual-jwt-validation/blob/master/TodoListService-ManualJwt/Global.asax.cs) shows a custom validation handler. In my case it throws an exception at tokenHandler.ValidateToken(). The comment says "authorization_uri" & "audience" is missing. I suppose I need to send these two with the token. Should i send it via header? If so what name should i use for key?

Comment: if access token includes correct permission .with access token in request header , you could make a call to your own apis/microsoft hosted apis (no matter in anjular app or tool like fiddler) .

Comment: If you are using ADAL.js to call an Azure AD protected Web API in an AngularJS Single Page App . In web api  , you could validate the access token with UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication as shown in [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-angularjs-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi/blob/master/ToGoAPI/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs) .

Comment: Don't forget to enable cors on the Api side.